# Is it possible to start a workflow only when a specific column is changed?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I created a workflow with "start on change" and I was wondering if it is possible that the worklfow only starts if a specific column of mine changes ("reminder_send"; YES; NO).

Because sometimes I have to correct some column information and I dont want the workflow to start up.
Starting the workflow for all items (>100) manually is... inhuman.

Answer (score 2):

You can also first start the workflow. In the first step of your workflow you can check if the field matches the criteria.

If so run the workflow normally otherwise end the workflow.

In your case if you like to update > 100 items and won't let the workflow to be started. All  you need to do is to set the workflow to "No New Instances". This can be set on "Remove Workflow" in the list or library settings.
After you finished updating the items this can be set to "Allow" again and workflows will start normally.
[image: Workflow configuration how to start]

Answer (score 1):

You could start the workflow with an event receiver (nintex does this and calls it "conditional start") - IMHO this is the only option without handling this in a workflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to accomplish this programmatically...

1. Create a ItemUpdating event handler and attach it to your target list. I would create a feature and feature receiver to do the attaching.
2. In the ItemUpdating event handler, there are two values you want to look at: properties.ListItem["reminder_send"] this will give you the original value and  properties.AfterProperties["reminder_send"] this is the updated value.

Check if the two values are not equal to each other, and if the updated value is equal to "Yes". If both are true, start a workflow on the list item programmatically- here are some links to help you with that:

http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/09/how-to-start-workflow-programmatically.html

http://www.tonytestasworld.com/post/Howto-Start-a-Sharepoint-Workflow-Programmatically.aspx

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179762/how-to-trigger-a-sharepoint-workflow-by-updating-only-a-value-in-a-list-item-ap)

In case of SPD Workflow,

• Open you site in SharePoint Designer

• Click File New WorkFlow

• Choose your List/Library

• Add a Condition: Compare ListName Field (you can compare values in the field in your case your reminder_send column)

Have a look at the below Links too,

1. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/watch-this-run-a-workflow-when-a-specific-field-changes-HA010256419.aspx
2. http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/
3. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f0ba8ba1-f9e4-49c9-9d0e-b4a7347dadff/site-workflow-error-this-workflow-association-is-not-valid-for-use-with-this-item?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: If you find my above answer is correct, please mark it as answer, so that it will be helpful to others :)