# Picture Library with workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I have a Picture Library with a workflow(SPD) that runs when an item is created or modified. I need to update a url field (since I cant seem to usel lookup's).
The problem is that when an image is uploaded, SP automatically redirects to the edit page. When the edit page is saved an error is reported. 
Is it possible to make the SPD to wait until file upload and dialog completed?

```
 [COMException (0x81020037): 0x81020015The file PictureLib/logo.png has been modified by STEVE on 14 Oct 2014 13:23:38 +0100.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback) +420
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a status field in your picture library and use this to make conditions in your workflow. So on upload the default status would be for example: "started" the workflow only updates the status field to "Uploaded" and then your existing workflow would start on the modify item event.

Please check the following urls:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179762/how-to-trigger-a-sharepoint-workflow-by-updating-only-a-value-in-a-list-item-ap

[Is it possible to start a workflow only when a specific column is changed?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/is-it-possible-to-start-a-workflow-only-when-a-specific-column-is-changed)

Hope this helps.